# Adding json file to MANIFEST.in and installing package results in an error

Tags: python, setuptools, distribute

My package tree looks like this: (with a few more irrelevant files)

```
- setup.py
- MANIFEST.in
- mydir
  |
  - file.py
  - file.json
```

setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name = 'mydir',
    packages = ['mydir'], 
    version = '1.2.2',
    description = 'desc',
    author = 'my name',
    author_email = 'my@email.com',
    url = 'https://github.com/myname/mydir', 
    download_url = 'https://github.com/myname/mydir/archive/1.2.2.tar.gz',
    keywords = ['key1', 'key2'],
    classifiers = [],
  )
```

When the `MANIFEST.in` file was empty, the json wasn't included in the dist file.
So I've added the json file to the `MANIFEST.in` so now it contains only:

```
include mydir/file.json
```

When I execute the `python setup.py sdist` command, the auto generated `MANIFEST` file contains all the necessary files, including `file.json`.
However, as I try to install my package using `pip`, I get the following error:

```
error: can't copy 'file.json': doesn't exist or not a regular file
```

Comment: Can you post your setup.py file?

Comment: @fasouto updated. thanks

Comment: I think include_package_data is missing :)

Comment: @fasouto you are right, but this alone wasn't enough, I had to change the lib used for `setup.py` from `distutils.core` to `setuptools`, see solution below

Comment: I wonder, what if you want to use `file.json` in `file.py`, what is the correct way to get the file path?

Answer (score 4):

Got it.
Changed `setup.py` to use `from setuptools import setup, find_packages` instead of `distutils.core`
Also added `include_package_data = True,` to `setup.py`:

```
setup(
    ...
    include_package_data = True,
    ...
)
```

together with the include in the `MANIFEST.in`, the json file was extracted to the target dir as expected.